# What is __alloca_probe_16 and what does it do?

Tags: ida, assembly

I'm reverse engineering some windows application. I came accross with this function that IDA recognized:

```
call __alloca_probe_16
```

I'm unable to find any documentation/reference on this function except [here](http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel.narkive.com/i2VrpN4F/function-of-alloc-probe). The poster suggests that `__alloca_probe` is a support routine for the API `_alloca()` without providing any reference.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows what this function does and where I can find reference to undocumented/internal(?) APIs like this in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This funcion enures that an `alloca()` call returns  a pointer aligned to 16 bytes boundary. You can see the comments in `alloca16.asm` in Visual C++' CRT sources:

```
; _alloca_probe_16, _alloca_probe_8 - align allocation to 16/8 byte boundary
;
;Purpose:
;       Adjust allocation size so the ESP returned from chkstk will be aligned
;       to 16/8 bit boundary. Call chkstk to do the real allocation.
;Entry:
;       EAX = size of local frame
;
;Exit:
;       Adjusted EAX.
;
;Uses:
;       EAX
```

NB: this comment seems to be stale; the current implementation tail-calls `_chkstk`, so the allocation (ESP adjustment) happens immediately.